# Set constant value with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I just moved to the android gradle build system and it is not clear for me how to set constant values.

e.g. I have

`API.java` which contains

```
BASE_URL = "http://debug.server.com"
```

but when gradle builds release I need `BASE_URL` to be `"http://release.server.com"`

How to replace this value at the build time?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Gradle generates a class called `BuildConfig` which contains static members (such as the boolean `DEBUG`, which is set to true for debug variants).

You could either query this in java like so:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    BASE_URL = "http://debug.server.com"
} else {
    BASE_URL = "http://release.server.com"
}
```

or the same thing as a one-liner:

```
BASE_URL = BuildConfig.DEBUG ? "http://debug.server.com" : "http://release.server.com"
```

---

**OR**

You could actually set the `BASE_URL` inside the the `BuildConfig` class using gradle like so:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://debug.server.com"'
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"http://release.server.com"'
        }
    }
}
```

Note the ***single and double quotations*** around the value in gradle, as others have mentioned in the comments. This way, the double quotes become part of the value.

As a result, the static reference `BuildConfig.BASE_URL` would point to the corresponding URL (i.e. "debug.server.com" for debug, "release.server.com" for release)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will use second approach, it is very flexible

Comment: Your answer only works for me if I use double quotes instead of single ones, and escape URL strings, like this:

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://debug.server.com\""
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField  "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://release.server.com\""
        }
    }
}

Comment: @falvarez - not sure why you're needing double quotes, as the single quote will set the string as you'd expect. It must be something to do with the way you code handles the url?

Comment: I had to use double quotes on it all too.

Comment: The only reason I can think of where quote type would matter is if your String is interpolated. Regardless, I've changed the answer to use double quotes as this should work fine in all cases.

Comment: You can use combination of single and double quotes: ' "
example: '"http://domain"'

Comment: Yes you have to use two sets of quotes, or you'll get some error like : `error: ';' expected public static final String BASE_URL = http://www.x.com`. seems like the `:` after http is confusing gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of fifer-sheep is correct. Just wanted to leave a solution for more than two environments.

Two flavors for staging and live.

```
productFlavors {
    staging {
        ...
    }
    production {
        ...
    }
}
```

Whole app config relies on the current ENV. Using:

```
public static String ENV_DEVELOPMENT = "development";
public static String ENV_STAGING = "staging";
public static String ENV_PRODUCTION = "production";

ENV = BuildConfig.DEBUG ? ENV_DEVELOPMENT : BuildConfig.FLAVOR;
```

I can switch between all different ENVs while testing locally but force staging/live settings if released.